# Задача 1. Даны оценки учащегося по 5 предметам в 12 бальной шкале. Вывести номера предметов, по которым у учащегося тройки?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Нужно найти индексы елементов,только я не знаю как.Нужно вывести на екран индексы елементов(тройки)

```
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let userNumber = parseInt(prompt("Введите число"));
        arr.push(userNumber);
      }
      function get5Scores(fiveScores) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
          switch (fiveScores) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
              return 1;
              break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
              return 2;
              break;
            case 6:
            case 7:
              return 3;
            case 8:
            case 9:
              return 4;
            case 10:
            case 11:
            case 12:
              return 5;
            default:
              throw Error(`Eror`);
              break;
          }
        }
      }
      let result = arr.map(get5Scores);
      let finalResult;
      function name(arr, finalResult) {
        for (let c = 0; c < result.length; c++) {
          return (finalResult = result.findIndex((el) => el === 3));
        }
      }
      let result3 = result.map(name);
      alert(result3);
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Вопросы на Stackoverflow принято задавать на **русском** языке, таковы правила сообщества. Отредактировать вопрос можно кнопкой [**Править**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1457042/edit).

Comment: Тройки - это в 12 бальной системе или в классической 5ти бальной? и не плохо было бы показать исходные данные

Comment: а я на каком языке задал?

Comment: 3 в пятибальной системе.я сначала перевожу 12 бальную в 5 бальную,затем я создаю новый массив(с помощью map),а потом я хочу чтобы мне на экран писало индексы(больше 1) нового массива которые равняються 3 по 5 бальной системе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо просто проверять условие, что значение это 3 и сразу возвращать индекс этого элемента.

Код можно записать так:

```js
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let userNumber = parseInt(prompt("Введите число"));
  arr.push(userNumber);
}
const result = [];
function get5Scores(fiveScores, index) {
    if (fiveScores > 5 && fiveScores <= 7) {
        result.push(index);
    }
}

arr.forEach(get5Scores)
console.log('res', result)

// Или с использованием метода reduce
console.log(arr.reduce( (acc, fiveScores, index) => {
  if (fiveScores > 5 && fiveScores <=7) acc.push(index)
  return acc;
  }, []))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое